# Deduct Parameter Pack Arguments for Lambda Functor

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, closures

I have a class that I want to use to execute a callback on an EventQueue:

```cpp
template <class, class>
class Handler;

template <class Fun, class... Args>
class Handler<void(Args...)>
{
public:
    Handler(events::EventQueue &eq, Fun fun) : _eq(eq), _fun(fun)
    {}

    void operator()(Args... args)
    {
        _eq.call(this, &Handler::callInternal, args...);
    }

private:
    events::EventQueue &_eq;
    Fun _fun;

    void callInternal(Args... args)
    {
        _fun(args...);
    }
};
```

where EventQueue::call(...) takes an object pointer, a method pointer, and the arguments with which to call the method.

I would really like to instantiate an object of type Handler with an rvalue lamba expression, e.g.

```cpp
makeHandler([](int result) { ... });
```

I don't care if I have to use a helper method, such as `makeHandler` to construct the Handler.

But something along these lines didn't work for me:

```cpp
template <class Fun, class... Args>
Handler<Fun, void(Args...)> makeHandlerInternal(events::EventQueue &eq, Fun fun, void (Fun::*)(Args...) const)
{
    return Handler<Fun, void(Args...)>(eq, fun);
}

template <class Fun, class... Args>
Handler<Fun, void(Args...)> makeHandler(events::EventQueue &eq, Fun fun)
{
    return Handler<Fun, void(Args...)>(eq, fun, &Fun::operator());
}
```

because Args... seems to be deduced to be an empty list before I can define it to be the arguments that Fun::operator() takes.

On a side note: is there a really good resource to strengthen template programming skills with problems such as this?

Comment: I think your primary template is incorrect: it should be just `template <class> class Handler;` rather than `template <class, class> class Handler;`.

Comment: Also the specialization has an unused parameter, `class Fun`.

Comment: Good books about templates: *C++ Templates: The Complete Guide* (D.Vandevoorde, N.Josuttis), *C++ Template Metaprogramming* (D.Abrahams, A.Gurtovoy), *Advanced C++ Metaprogramming* (D.Di Gennaro), *Modern C++ Design* (A.Alexandrescu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is almost correct. I don't see a good reason to convert `Args...` into `void(Args...)` and suggest the following solution:

```
// This stub is here for the sake of code completeness only
class EventQueue {
public:
    template<class T, class Fun, class... Args>
    void call(T* obj, Fun fun, Args... args) const {
        std::invoke(fun, obj, args...);
    }
};

template<class Fun, class... Args>
class Handler {
public:
    Handler(EventQueue& eq, Fun fun) : eq_(eq), fun_(fun) {}

    void operator()(Args... args) {
        eq_.call(this, &Handler::callInternal, args...);
    }

private:
    EventQueue& eq_;
    Fun fun_;

    void callInternal(Args... args) {
        fun_(args...);
    }
};

template<class Fun, class... Args>
auto makeHandlerImpl(EventQueue& eq, Fun fun, void (Fun::*)(Args...) const) {
    return Handler<Fun, Args...>(eq, fun);
}

template<class Fun>
auto makeHandler(EventQueue& eq, Fun fun) { 
    return makeHandlerImpl(eq, fun, &Fun::operator());
}

EventQueue eq;
auto handler = makeHandler(eq, [](int result) { std::cout << result; });
handler(2020); // prints 2020
```

---

Alternatively, you could drop `Args...` from `Handler` type, but make `operator()` a template, getting something like this:

```
template<class Fun>
class Handler {
public:
    Handler(EventQueue& eq, Fun fun) : eq_(eq), fun_(fun) {}

    template<class... Args>
    void operator()(Args... args) {
        // static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<Fun, Args...>);
        eq_.call(this, &Handler::callInternal<Args...>, args...);
    }

private:
    EventQueue& eq_;
    Fun fun_;

    template<class... Args>
    void callInternal(Args... args) {
        fun_(args...);
    }
};
```

Now, with C++17 [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), you can simply write:

```
EventQueue eq;
Handler handler(eq, [](int result) { std::cout << result; });
handler(2020);  // prints 2020
```

without any special helper functions.

Comment: This did the trick.
The reason I tried to fix Handler to be void(Args...) is that EventQueue::call posts the callback onto a queue for the callback to be called later. At that point returning a value is nonsensical since there is nowhere to return the value to. But I went with your second suggestion for now to make it work. I might check traits of the passed-in template types later with static_assert